# Trajectory of tent map

Tags: ergodic-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Find a point x $\in$ [0,1] whose trajectory under the action of the tent map Tx = 1−$\mid$1−2x$\mid$ is everywhere dense. 
I know fixed points x=0 and x=$\frac{2}{3}$ are, but I don't know how to find others.

Comment: what's the difference between "everywhere dense" and "dense"

Comment: I guess "everywhere dense" means a trajectory can pass some regions a lot times, but these regions can be disjoint.

Comment: I still don't get it. Formulate a completely rigorous, well-defined question or delete your question.